# node.js and telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I need to use a telegram bot to call a route of a website.
In the website, in `routes.js` , i have:

```
app.get('/api/getalert', getAlert);
```

and

```
var getAlert = function(req, res) {
        var id = req.query.id;
        Alert.find({})
            .sort({
                "alertStatus.date": -1
            })
            .limit(1)
            .exec(
                function(err, alert) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500).send(err)
                    };
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(alert, null, 4));
                    res.json(alert);
                });
    };
```

in the telegram bot I have:

```
bot.on("/alarm", msg => {
  let fromId = msg.from.id;

  var options = {
    host: "my.website",
    port: 3333,
    path: "/api/getalert"

  };

  var callback = function(res) {
    res.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log('data is '+data);
      console.log('name is: '+data.name);
    });
  }

  var req = http.get(options, callback)
    .on('error', function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
)};

bot.connect();
```

the result of `console.log(data)` is similar to this:

```
data is 
[{
"_id":"585d08455733bb63a19b0b4d",
"name":"Alert",
"description":"Alert description",
"address":"an_address ",
"__v":0,
"alertStatus": 
    [{"_id":"585d08455733bb63a19b0b4c",
      "date":"2016-12-23T11:19:33.608Z",
      "status":1
    }],
"users":[42711895,85811757],
"range":1000,
"position":{"lat":11,"lng":12}
}]
```

But.

With `console.log(data[0])` it prints just `91` .

With `console.log(data.name)` it prints `undefined` .

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 91 is the ASCII code for `[`, so I think you need to parse the JSON first. Try `var parsedData = JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_json_parse

Comment: Is there a special reason why you save an `id` variable? You don't seem use it anywhere.

Comment: @Tomalak no, it's a typo =)

Comment: @Roberg I tried `console.log('data is '+JSON.parse(data));
      console.log('name is: '+ JSON.parse(data.name));`

and the result is

`data is [object Object]
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` ....this make no sense to me!

Comment: Now I tried `console.log('data is '+JSON.stringify(data));` and result is

`data is {"type":"Buffer","data":[91,123......]}` , a series of numbers. However, if I try `console.log('data is '+JSON.stringify(data.data));` or data.type, it says `undefined`

Comment: You're getting close.. `data.name` does not exist. You want the `name` attribute of the parsed data string. So `console.log('data name is '+JSON.parse(data)[0].name)` should do the trick..

Comment: @Roberg nope :( it says `undefined:1
[{"_id":"585d08455733bb63a19b0b4d","name":"Alert","description":"...[prints the rest]   }}
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: @Roberg I did a workaround and it works, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do that.

First I realized that it was an Async answer, so data didn't arrive completely at first. so i did:

`var callback = function(res) {
var result="";
    res.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log('data arrived');
      if(data != 'undefined') result+=JSON.parse(data);
});

    res.on("end", function(res) {
      console.log('end data');

      var parsedRes = JSON.parse(result);
console.log('name is ' + parsedRes[0].name);`

This works...but how can I write this in a cleaner way?

Comment: some changes....

https://jsfiddle.net/31wjb9og/6/

Comment: I think you are better off using `request` instead of `http`. `request({uri: "http://my.website/api/getalert",json:true},function (error, response, jsonData) {});` https://github.com/request/request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got a solution... I received data in chunks, then merged the single chunks, then on `'end'` I concatenated the chunks and parsed them:

```
var callback = function(res) {
    var dataChunks = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      dataChunks.push(chunk);
    })

    .on('end', function() {
      //obj will contain the objects received
      var obj = Buffer.concat(dataChunks);
      //all objects in JSON format
      var stringObj = JSON.parse(obj);
      //test to check if it works
      console.log(stringObj[0].users);
    })

  }
```